# Rsync : overwrite log file

Tags: rsync

In rsync, --log-file creates a log file, however, if i do a daily backup, the log is appended to the previous log file.  How can i force rsync to overwrite the log file instead of appending to it?

Comment: COuldn't you just delete it before starting the next backup? Though moving it out of the way (possibly using logrotate) might be better.

Comment: I thought of adding a line to delete it in the crontab but did not like it as a solution and i thought i leave this as a last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that you cannot (unless you compile your own `rsync` binary).

`rsync` always appends to the log file. So as suggested in the comments you should delete the log before running `rsync`. A simple example of removing the log and then running `rsync` is:

```
rm rsync.log; rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]
```

These might also be helpful:

1. https://serverfault.com/questions/219440/rsync-via-cron-how-do-i-enable-logging
2. https://superuser.com/questions/545642/is-it-possible-to-make-rsync-make-a-log-file-on-a-remote-system